# Consulta en JPA con oracle uso del Group By para agrupar datos da error

Tags: java, oracle, jpa

Tengo una consulta sql en Java Jpa la cual ya probe en SqlDeveloper y funciona bien pero al implementarla en `@Query` me indica el siguiente error.

Desarrollo con: ojdbc8 y Spring Boot 2.2.6.RELEASE

`no es una expresión GROUP BY` Mi entity class java se llama Download uso la d en varias y funciona normal pero en esta recibo el error por el group by y ya agregue en el group los datos que tengo en el select.

```
@Query("SELECT d.iddocumento, d.terminal, d.status,sum(d.partSize) as part_size, d.totalSize from Download d GROUP BY d.iddocumento, d.terminal, d.status, d.totalSize")
    Page<Download> getDescargas(Pageable pageable);
```

Comment: O tenés una columna que se llama `d` y la estás omitiendo en el `GROUP BY`, o `d` está demás en el `SELECT` (la columna que está antes de `d.iddocumento`).

Comment: d es el alias asi lo tengo en unos y funciona pero incluso sin el d , no funciona me da el mismo error del group by

Comment: El alias no está mal; en la consulta dice `SELECT d, d.iddocumento, d.terminal ...` y es a la primera `d` a la que toma también como columna.

Comment: Ya edite mi código y en el Query esta como debería ser pero sigue con el error comentado